# WordPress comments plugin with pagination

Tags: wordpress

I've tried different plugins and none seem to perform this simple task. I just want to create a comments page on my WordPress website. Does anyone know of any WordPress plugins that display all comments on a single page with pagination?

Answer (score 0):

Try this plug in: https://wordpress.org/plugins/show-all-comments-in-one-page/

I have used this one for that purpose.

Comment: It's a good idea to not answer low quality, off-topic questions, as it simply encourages more of the same.

Comment: Ah, ok will do. Didn't know that.

Comment: Thank you!. I made some minor css changes but otherwise it works well.